# Moq library and .NET core preview 3.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq

How can I make the Moq library work with .NET core preview 3.x ? Is it possible at all?

Specifically, when I enable Moq there is a conflict with the logging library:

```
MyProjectTest.cs(25, 45): [CS1705] :

Assembly 'MyProject' with identity 'MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
uses 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' 

which has a higher version than referenced assembly 

'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions' with identity
 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** The updated version of the question has nothing to do with `Moq`. You need to make sure that all dependencies are updated properly. `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` is not referenced by `Moq`.

**Edit2:** Here a [sample](https://github.com/alsami/NetCore3.Moq).

Yes, it is possible. The [current version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) (as of now 4.12.0), supports .NET-Standard 2.0. That is fully supported by .NET-Core 3.0 so you would use it like you always did.

```
var mock = new Mock<ISomeService>(MockBehavior.Loose);
mock.Setup(someService => someService.IsValidString(it.IsAny<string>)
   .Returns(true);
```

You can find more samples in the [docs](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I updated my question with more detail :)

Comment: I updated the answer, your problem has nothing to do with `.NET-Core 3`

Comment: Thanks for your help. The solution was to explicitly force packages '.Extensions.Options` and `.Extension.Logging.Abstractions` to `3.0.0-previewX`.